# What is the best way to migrate code from external consultant?

Tags: migration-tool, migration, git, organization-wide

I am planning to hire consultant, but I am puzzled with the simplest question. How to manage code with him or her. We do not have available sandboxes right now. He or she can open free development organization, but then I do not know how to migrate changes from that external organization to any of our sandboxes. The only way I see now is to tell the consultant to commit apex code, visualforce code and objects changes to Git, and then I'll move it to my organization manualy.

Is it the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually moving is not scalable and there will be additional challenges like everytime your external developer org needs to sync the changes you do to your sandbox organisation .

The scalable and long term solution would be to set up a continuous  Integration Process (CI) along with git worlflow to manage the Code merging .

There are lot of open source projects that have already done some work in this space and you can reuse this .You will need a server or a CI tool like Circle CI .Check the cummulus CI workflow [here](http://developer.salesforce.org/CumulusCI/) from NPSP and see how they manage the developer workflow.

The key ingredient is you will need a server like Tomcat + Jenkins or any other alternative CI cloud tools like Autorabit ,Circle or appexchange products